# Why is ArcGIS calculating polygon area twice bigger?

Tags: polygon, geometry, surface

I am trying to determine size of surface area of the examined patches. I drew a polygon on the outlines of the patches and used geometry to calculate the area (following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3AJ6V4V6U0&ab_channel=Geo-SpatialTutorials).

The problem is that area sizes that are being calculated by the programme are aprox. twice bigger than they really are (I double checked on some other map). This makes me believe that probably the map scale is also too big.

Any solutions?

**Edit:**
I am using ArcMap 10.4.1. The country of the features is Slovenia and CRS is WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere. To double check I used an online map of Slovenia that has a tool to calculate area if you mark the outline with points.

Comment: Please provide details on the CRS you're working in and the country the features are situated in. Also, what does "I double checked on some other map" mean? And how do you know that the returned areas are inaccurate?

Comment: When you say “ArcGIS” do you mean ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or something else from that platform?

Comment: Web Mercator isn't ever accurate in calculating area, period. ArcMap can calculate area correctly, but you need to reproject and calculate geodesic area in your computation. You need to provide an exact methodology before we can correct it.